# Will Packets Out of Order From Network Card to Epoll?

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, network-programming, epoll

Let's say I have some multicast UDP packets arrive at my network card in the following order:
A,B,C,D,E,F
for file descriptors (socket IDs) 1, 2 and 3.

And let's say I have an epoll instance that has lever trigger on those 3 file descriptors above.

Does `epoll_wait()` guarantee to return the list of file descriptors based on the order of packet arrival above so that my application will read A, B, C, D, E, and then F?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you care? There's no order guarantees about UDP packet arrival anyway. Essentially, if you care, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: yes or no, if epoll guarantees the order, then anyone tries to write a piece of code that mimic epoll should provide the same guarantee.

Comment: Fair enough. But the documentation for `epoll` makes no such guarantee, thus no code implementing the `epoll` interface is required to provide the same guarantee.